# How can I monitor what are the most frequently accessed URL's on my servers?

Tags: performance-monitoring

What enterprise software can I use to monitor the most frequently accessed URL's on my servers? I'm familiar with load testing software, but need something that can monitor real loads. Also, software such as Nagios seem to be centered around monitoring node and application-level statistics, rather than web-page / web-server statistics.

Comment: Google Analytics should work http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/meuAKawvggY

Comment: @TheCleaner unless its blocked by an incantation of NoScript or its derivatives. Also there are times when you dont want a third party getting the data. For everything else, there is Google.

Comment: ...or use piwik and avoid the third party issue.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're after something like [awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/), which can generate a variety of useful statistics and pretty graphs.

[image: pretty Awstats graph]